# Grab a reference on the last thrown exception

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace, callstack

In the python and/or ipython interactive interpreter, how can I get name bound on the last unhandled exception?  I.e. the equivalent of

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except Exception as potato:
...     pass
... 
>>> format(potato)
'integer division or modulo by zero'
```

Must be something like...

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> import sys
>>> potato = ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`sys.last_value`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.last_value) for this:

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> sys.last_value
ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
>>> type(sys.last_value)
<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `ipython` with the `--pdb` switch to dump you into the python debugger (pdb) when an unhandled exception is raised.

```
$ ipython --pdb
In [1]: 1/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-05c9758a9c21> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
> /usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(177)_set_stopinfo()
    176     def _set_stopinfo(self, stopframe, returnframe, stoplineno=0):
--> 177         self.stopframe = stopframe
    178         self.returnframe = returnframe

ipdb> whatis
*** SyntaxError: SyntaxError('unexpected EOF while parsing', ('<string>', 0, 0, ''))
ipdb> where
  /usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(43)reset()
     41         linecache.checkcache()
     42         self.botframe = None
---> 43         self._set_stopinfo(None, None)
     44 
     45     def trace_dispatch(self, frame, event, arg):

> /usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(177)_set_stopinfo()
    175 
    176     def _set_stopinfo(self, stopframe, returnframe, stoplineno=0):
--> 177         self.stopframe = stopframe
    178         self.returnframe = returnframe
    179         self.quitting = 0
```

The documentation for `pdb` is here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html